# Can I use present perfect tense and simple past tense in the same sentence

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Can you please tell me whether these sentences are true grammatically or not? I used past tense and present perfect tense in the same sentence but I am not sure about it. It is a part of my very important assignment.

> Hours spent in online multiplayer gaming per week, that wasn't more than 2 hours before, has increased dramatically in 2014 after which it continued to increase considerably and it started to be played 10 hours per week in 2018.

Comment: It's a very poorly constructed sentence.

Comment: so, how can I fix it?

Comment: _Hours spent in online multiplayer gaming per week, that was previously 2 hours, increased dramatically in 2014 after which it continued to increase. Reaching 10 hours per week in 2018._

Comment: Thank you so much ^^